# Change background by season using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, variables

I'm trying to figure out how to change my website's background by season using CSS and Javascript.  It seems like it should be easy but I'm just not getting anywhere on it.  Here's what I was trying, which doesn't work (of course, right?):

```
<script>
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;

// Summer
if (total >= 6 && total <= 8)
{
var season = "summer.jpg";
}
// Autumn
else if (total >= 9 && total <= 11)
{
var season = "fall.jpg";
}
// Winter
else if (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2)
{
var season = "winter.jpg";
}
// Spring
else if (total >= 2 && total <= 6)
{
var season = "spring.jpg";
}
else
{
var season = "summer.jpg";
}
</script>

<style  type="text/css">

#maincontent{
position: fixed; 
left: 200px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
top: 0px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: auto; 
background-image: url('season');  /*Note: I tried putting season in <scirpt>   tags too with no success */

</style>
```

Comment: So, is the image just not showing up regardless of "season"? Or is it showing up, but not changing with the season?

Comment: You can't change the background-image property with javascript. I'd recommend you to create 4 different classes for each season and change your logic to add the correct class based on the season.

Comment: yes you can....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;
switch(total) {
  case (total >= 6 && total <= 8):
    var season = "summer.jpg";
    break;
  case (total >= 9 && total <= 11):
    var season = "fall.jpg";
    break;
  case (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2):
    var season = "winter.jpg";
    break;
   default:
    var season = "summer.jpg";
  }
 var output = "red url('" + season + "') no-repeat center center fixed";
 var content= document.getElementById('maincontent');

 content.style.background = output;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Pure Javascript to set background images according to your conditions. For reference I've added a text that shows you the current season.

Please have a look at the code below.

```js
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;
var total = month;

console.log('currentTime: ', currentTime);
console.log('month: ', month);
console.log('total: ', total);

var myElement = document.querySelector("#maincontent");
var textSelector = function(divId) {
  var textElement = document.getElementById(divId);
  return textElement;
}


// Summer
if (total >= 6 && total <= 8)
{
var season = "summer.jpg";
myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/500x500')";
  textSelector('seasonOne').innerHTML = 'Season (Summer)';
}
// Autumn
else if (total >= 9 && total <= 11)
{
var season = "fall.jpg";
myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/500x500')";
  textSelector('seasonTwo').innerHTML = 'Season (Fall)';
}
// Winter
else if (total == 12 || total == 1 || total == 2)
{
var season = "winter.jpg";
  myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/500x500')";
  textSelector('seasonThree').innerHTML = 'Season (Winter)';
}
// Spring
else if (total >= 2 && total <= 6)
{
var season = "spring.jpg";
  myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/500x500')";
  textSelector('seasonThree').innerHTML = 'Season (Spring)';
}
else
{
var season = "summer.jpg";
  myElement.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://placehold.it/500x500')";
  textSelector('seasonThree').innerHTML = 'Season (Summer)';
}
```

```css
#maincontent {
  position: fixed; 
  left: 200px; /*Set left value to WidthOfLeftFrameDiv*/
  top: 0px; /*Set top value to HeightOfTopFrameDiv*/
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto; 
  background-image: url('season');
  background: #aaa;
}

.txt {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div id="maincontent">
  <div id="seasonOne" class="txt"></div>
  <div id="seasonTwo" class="txt"></div>
  <div id="seasonThree" class="txt"></div>
  <div id="seasonFour" class="txt"></div>
  <div id="seasonFive" class="txt"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Its great but you repeat a lot of code in the if-else section

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answers switch statement doesn't actually work, this really annoyed and confused me for a while, solution is to use 'true' as the switch argument:

```
var currentTime = new Date();
var month = currentTime.getMonth() + 1;

switch(true) {
  case (month >= 6 && month <= 8):
    var season = "summer.jpg";
    break;
  case (month >= 9 && month <= 11):
    var season = "fall.jpg";
    break;
  case (month == 12 || month == 1 || month == 2):
    var season = "winter.jpg";
    break;
   default:
    var season = "summer.jpg";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using jquery,

after assigned value for season do like below,

```
  $("#maincontent").css("background-image","url(" + season + ")");
```

By using javascript,

```
document.getElementById("maincontent").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + season + ")";
```

Comment: this is jquery, he asked in js

Comment: @felix91 are you okay with this now

Comment: @felix91 but I did it quite optimistically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var main = document.getElementById('maincontent');
main.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + season + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the style inline...

```
var maincontent = document.getElementById("#maincontent");
var season = "summer";

if (condition) {
   season = "fall"
}

// list all your conditions

maincontent.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + season + ".jpg)";
```